# How to I get the Shadow Price in Python OR-Tools MIP problem

Tags: python, or-tools

So basically I using OR-Tools in Python and I would like to know how to extract the Shadow Price of the constraints. I tought about just changing the parameters of the constraints and runing the model again but it has to have a better way to do that. If anyone could enlight me on this matter I would aprecciate!

ps: I don't think that my code would help to solve this question but, by way means, if you need the code to help me i can post here as well

Comment: If you have code. It's better to post it. Because sometime it makes more sense to the answer giver

Answer (score 0):

When integer variables are involved there is no derivative for the constraints that include them. Therefore, the shadow price of constraints of problems including integer variables *makes no sense*. Some solvers provide the shadow values of the LP problem for the final integer set of variables. Personally, this is what I usually want.

Apparently, ortools chose to not to provide shadow values ever for MIP problems. You may want to check with them via a github issue and clarify this.